# Centering elements on scroll load

Tags: css

I'm loading elements on scroll. The elements are put into container like:

```html
<div class="viewer" v-if="resp <= 1023">
  <div class="view" id="the-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```css
.viewer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 90vh;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.view {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color:orangered;
}
```

A single element is centered fine. `width: fit-content` fits the width as it should. When now loading more elements the width of the inner container sets to the width of the outer one. How comes? Shouldn't it still be the width of the child elements?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
background-color: white;
```

to the `.view` class. Simple as that, but it did the trick.
This also guaranteed the overflow and scaling ability  I needed for the canvas elements.

The answer by @Marghen is also valid in general, just not for my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

width: fit-content; is not fully supported on all browsers at the moment, you could just remove that and instead set the element as:

```
.view {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: orangered;
}
```

It should behave just as you wanted to. The idea is that display:flex automatically fits its content without specifying anything else.

You should also set a max-height to make sure, and set the overflow as **auto** and not scroll as scroll can give you some troubles on safari.

Comment: This makes the elements appear next to each other instad of underneath. But `flex-direction: column` did it.

Comment: My fault, I forgot to add that I'm sorry. I wrote the answer from the top of my mind, glad it worked!

Comment: I just recognized - yor answer works. But not in my specific case. I am loading canvas elements (for pdfjs) when scrolling. And those elements need to be scaled and got overflow on mobile. And this overflow is denied by flexbox, same as the scaling itself.

Comment: Did you try with display:inline-block ? You should achieve the same effect

Comment: I did - it's just the case with using pdfjs and the textlayer scaling that's not working properly. ^^